# RandomForestSRC: how to get survival probabilities for any time point?

Tags: r, random-forest, predict, survival-analysis

I am using the `randomForestSRC` package to model some survival data. I train the model using the `rfsrc` function. My train data is heavily censored, the event occurs only in 1% of the cases. The observation times range from 3 months and up to 13 years, however, all the events occur within first 2 years, and the rest is right-censored data. I want to use the model to predict survival probabilities on the test dataset and I am interested in predicted probabilities for different time points (1 year, 3 years, 5 years after the patient enrolled the study). Is that possible using the random survival forests, since the survival probabilities returned by the prediction function only refer to the observed event times?

**Example**
I demonstrate my procedure on the veteran dataset, where we can see that the resulting prediction matrix is of dimensions 37x63 (*number of individuals in the test dataset* x *number of unique event times in the train dataset*) and the predicted survival probabilities correspond to the event times in the train dataset. My question is: how can I predict survival probabilities after the maximum observed event time? To be more concrete: in the case of veterans, how can make predictions for time = 500?

```
data(veteran, package = "randomForestSRC")

# order dataset by time and take first 100/137 rows as train data
# just for the sake of demonstrating the problem
veteran <- veteran[order(veteran$time), ]
train_dat <- veteran[1:100, ]
test_dat <- veteran[101:nrow(veteran), ]

# train model
veteran.grow <- rfsrc(Surv(time, status) ~ ., train_dat, ntree = 100)

# make predictions 
veteran.pred <- predict(veteran.grow, test_dat)

# Check dimensions of the matrix that predicts survival probabilities
dim(veteran.pred$survival)
[1] 37 63

# Check maximum survival time corresponding to the predicted probabilities
max(veteran.grow$time.interest)
[1] 139

# how to do predictions for time = 500?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality you are asking for is not implemented in the `randomForestSRC` package, that is you can only predict the survival function at times which are present in the training dataset.

However, the [survex package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survex), which is mainly for explanations of survival models also provides a functionality of a unified interface for making predictions. It can be done as shown in the example:

```
library(randomForestSRC)
library(survex)

data(veteran, package = "randomForestSRC")

veteran <- veteran[order(veteran$time), ]
train_dat <- veteran[1:100, ]
test_dat <- veteran[101:nrow(veteran), ]

veteran.grow <- rfsrc(Surv(time, status) ~ ., train_dat, ntree = 100)

explainer <- explain(veteran.grow)

pred <- predict(explainer, test_dat, output_type="survival", times=500)
dim(pred)
[1] 37  1
```

Comment: Thanks! In the end I also managed to do it with function predictSurvProb from the pec package. I also checked your solution and the output is the same with both libraries.